# Reading a binary file in perl - running out of memory

Tags: perl, memory, binary, filehandle

I want to read a large binary file (500MB) and fetch specific bytes located after a header which repeats every 5000 bytes. For that I have a short snippet reading the file in binary mode and block size of 16536.

The code works as intended, but eats out all of the available memory which makes it unusable. I tried closing and opening the parsed output file I write to every time a write operation should be done, but that doesn't help. Could the issue be linked to the way I am reading the binary file?

Here is my code:

```
use strict;

my $BLOCK_SIZE=16536;

my $fname = $ARGV[0];
my $fparsename = $ARGV[1];
open(F,"<$fname") or die("Unable to open file $fname, $!");
binmode(F);
my $buf;
my $ct=0;
my $byte=0;
my $byte_old=0;
my $byte_cnt=0;
my $byte_lock=0;
my $sample_msb=0;
my $sample_lsb=0;
my $sample_16b=0;
my $out_form='';

open(my $fh, '>', $fparsename) or die "Could not open file '$fparsename' $!";
print $fh ("Sample, Value \n");
close($fh);

while(read(F,$buf,$BLOCK_SIZE,$ct*$BLOCK_SIZE)){
    foreach(split(//, $buf)){

        $byte_old = $byte;
        $byte = ord($_);    # fetch byte (in decimal)


        if (($byte_old == 202) && ($byte == 254)) { # CA = 202, FE = 254
            $byte_cnt = 0;
            $byte_lock = 1;
        }

        if ($byte_lock == 1) {
            $byte_cnt++;
        }

        if ($byte_cnt == 20) {  # 20th byte after CAFE in header
            $sample_msb = $byte;
        }
        if ($byte_cnt == 21) {  # 21th byte after CAFE in header
            $sample_lsb = $byte;
        }

        if (($byte_cnt == 21) && ($byte_lock == 1)) {   # lock down and concatenate
            $byte_lock = 0;
            $byte_cnt = 0;
            $sample_16b = sprintf("%X", $sample_msb) . sprintf("%X", $sample_lsb);
            $out_form = sprintf("%d, %s \n", $ct++, $sample_16b);

            open(my $fh, '>>', $fparsename) or die "Could not open file '$fparsename' $!";
            printf $fh $out_form;
            close($fh);
        }

    }
    $ct++;

}
close(F);
close($fh);
```

Comment: Rather than using decimal numbers and commenting them `CA = 202, FE = 254` you should use `0xCA` and `0xFE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first off - the thing that eats memory is things that are held in memory. Closing and opening a file handle doesn't make any difference, because writes will be flushed as needed.

And I can't reproduce your problem, as I don't have a suitable sample file.

However I think your problem is that you've got your [`read`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html) wrong:

> An OFFSET may be specified to place the read data at some place in the string other than the beginning. A negative OFFSET specifies placement at that many characters counting backwards from the end of the string. A positive OFFSET greater than the length of SCALAR results in the string being padded to the required size with "\0" bytes before the result of the read is appended.

So... your 'last' read from the file, will create a string 500MB in length that's mostly null bytes. (it'll probably be bigger than 500MB of actual memory for various reasons)

This would most simply be fixed simply by omitting the offset in your `read`.

But failing that:

So I would look closer at your variables - in particular, you're scoping them all outside your loop, and the means they *might* be being concatenated, rather than rewritten.

I would also suggest that if you're iterating a file by the bytes, you can simplify greatly by setting `$/`. E.g.

```
local $/ = \16536

while ( my $buf = <$input> ) { 

}
```

From [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

> Setting $/ to a reference to an integer, scalar containing an integer, or scalar that's convertible to an integer will attempt to read records instead of lines, with the maximum record size being the referenced integer number of characters.

(Or as noted in the comments - given your 'chunks' are 5000 bytes, then setting `local $/ = \5000` would probably be sensible).

And I'd also suggest - use 3 arg open, not 2 arg:

```
open ( my $input, '<:raw', $fname ) or die $!;
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you chose `\16536` as `$/`.

Comment: I would set `local $/ = \5000` so that the "specific bytes" appear once in each chunk.

Comment: @simbabque - because that's what the OP set as his read size. As Borodin notes 5000 is probably more sensible given the OPs use case.

Comment: Oh, so that's the number of bytes that should be read. I wasn't aware of that. I guess it's documented somewhere. Maybe you can add that too.

Comment: As @Sobrique suggested the issue appeared to be in the way I was reading the file. I used your approach by setting local $/ = \16536. 16536 is the amount of bytes that I read and check for the 0xCA 0xFE starting pattern. Thanks for all your help.